# Why do I get a “Can't find string terminator” error only when the command is in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a simple shell script to get the version of Perl modules installed 
on a server and I keep receiving the following error:

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
mod_name="Sub::Uplevel"
tmp1="perl -M$mod_name -e 'print \"\$$mod_name::VERSION\"'"
echo $tmp1
$tmp1
```

If I just directly run the `echo`'d line (`perl -MSub::Uplevel -e 'print "$Sub::Uplevel::VERSION"'`), it works. Why doesn't the line work when its run from the variable `$tmp1`?

Comment: which flavor of unix you are using ? I just tried this step in Linux Ubuntu and it went fine, without any errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply Roopesh.  I'm using 2.6.18-92.el5/CentOS 5.2

Comment: @RoopeshMajeti: Bash 4.2.20(1) on Debian testing gives the error. So does `dash`. And `posh`. Surprised you're not getting it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place of just `$tmp1`, `eval` works:

```
eval "$tmp1"
```

That's because splitting a variable into words (for arguments) is done strictly by splitting on `$IFS`, not the normal input-parsing. `eval` forces the normal input parsing.

### How did I figure this out?

Change your `tmp1=` line to put an `echo` in front, and you get:

```
perl -MSub::Uplevel -e 'print "$Sub::Uplevel::VERSION"'
```

Note that the `'` are still there, which you wouldn't expect. If you write a quick script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for a in "$@"; do
    echo "arg: $a"
done
```

and put a call to that in place of echo, you find how the arguments are really split:

```
arg: perl
arg: -MSub::Uplevel
arg: -e
arg: 'print
arg: "$Sub::Uplevel::VERSION"'
```

So, you can see that's splitting on spaces, so IFS.

Comment: derobert, YES!! This works, but I need to store the results in a variable for comparison later in the code.

Comment: @GoinOff: Then you want to use `var=$(eval "$tmp1")`. Also, depending on what you're doing, possibly you just want to write the entire script in Perl. Also, speaking of Perl, you probably want `perl -MSub::Uplevel -e 'print Sub::Uplevel->VERSION'`—that is, you want to call the VERSION function (from UNIVERSAL).

Comment: I would use perl but this code is going to end up in an RPM SPEC file which can't be coded in Perl.  All is good now thx a TON for your help.. 8)

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
    #
    mod_name="Sub::Uplevel"
    tmp1="perl -M$mod_name -e 'print \"\$$mod_name::VERSION\"'"
    echo $tmp1
    tmp=$(eval "$tmp1")
    echo $tmp
    exit 0`

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to construct commands using bash arrays. That will keep arguments with whitespace properly grouped:

```
#!/bin/bash
mod_name="Sub::Uplevel"
perl_script=$(printf 'print "$%s::VERSION"' $mod_name)
tmp1=(perl -M$mod_name -e "$perl_script")
echo "${tmp1[@]}"
output=$( "${tmp1[@]}" )
```

Arrays are a bash feature, so the shebang line must reference `bash` not `sh`.

Comment: Glen, this also works perfectly!! Thanks for contributing.. 8)

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually write what you are doing with backticks, to run the command inside the shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
mod_name="Sub::Uplevel"
tmp1=`perl -M$mod_name -e 'print \"\$$mod_name::VERSION\"'`
echo $tmp1
```

Then you can work on `$tmp1` as needed. It also avoids dealing with escaping.

Comment: or even better, inside `$(perl …)` as that's much more readable, especially with all the quote characters inside the backticks. `$(foo)` syntax is part of POSIX, BTW, so should be everywhere (not just Bash)

Comment: Still receive an error doing it this way.  Backticks results in error and $(variable) also receives an error.  Since eval work OK, is there a way to store the results in a variable??

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the script the below way(debugging the script):

```
sh -vx your_script.sh
```

Then you would be able to see where exactly the problem is.
I donot have the shell to execute it right now.

Comment: Well, it's in the `$tmp1` line obviously. But since the `echo` immediately before it shows a perfectly good line of code (and indeed, copy & paste that echo output works), the question is why.

Comment: Executed with -vx option: $tmp1
+ perl -MSub::Uplevel -e ''\''print' '"$Sub::Uplevel::VERSION"'\'''
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.